# javascript use test with regex for letters, numbers, spaces and dash

Tags: javascript

I use a javascript test with regex for numbers, letters and underscore. I want to change the regex to regex for letters, numbers, spaces and dash. But how?

```
re = /^\w+$/; 
if(!re.test(form.username.value)) { 
    alert("Username must contain only letters, numbers and underscores. Please try again"); 
    form.username.focus();
    return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about this?

```
/^[0-9A-Za-z\s\-]+$/
```

Answer (score 7):

```
/^[\w\d\s-]+$/
```

- `^` from beginning
- `\w` letters
- `\d` digits
- `\s` space
- *and then the* `-` (dash)
- ^wrapping in `[ ]` matches any character within
- `$` to the end

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-\s]*$/;
if(!re.test(form.username.value)) { 
    alert("Username must contain only letters, numbers and dashes. Please try again"); 
    form.username.focus();
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: ^- Yep.  You could change `*` to `+`.  Unless that's a desired feature, of course.

Comment: I've updated the regex since the question states "to regex for letters, numbers, spaces and dash." .. there is no mention of underscore and as you said .. to force string it's enough to change * to +

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that the in the question right after I posted.

Answer (score -1):

```
  const reg = /^(?!.*\.\.)(?!.*\.$)[^\W][\w.\s\-']{2,200}$/gim;
  const regStatus = reg.test(value);
  return regStatus ? value : undefined;
```